# Changing the .NET application configuration file name

Tags: .net, app-config

I have a VB6 app which calls a .NET assembly, which references settings from the app.config file. By default, .NET looks for a config file named after the VB6 app. How can I redirect it to use a different config file name? This needs to become the default config file so that e.g. WCF settings are read from it.

Comment: Since there is already a system which defines the "default" configuration file, what are you trying to do that you need to change it?

Comment: I don't want it to be named after the VB6 app. I have several of these and would like to avoid having one copy of the config file for each, as the settings are not really specific to each app but to the .NET assembly.

Comment: In that case, you probably don't need to be using App.config to solve your problem, as its purpose is per-application settings. If the settings are supposed to be the same for the assembly regardless of application, aren't those just hard-coded values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't change it. Each AppDomain instance has a fixed app.config that is set via an **AppDomainSetup** instance when a new app domain is created. Although you can get the setup information via **AppDomain.SetupInformation** it has effectively become readonly at this point.

Given this, one option may be to create a new app domain from within your **Main** function and configure the domain to use the app.config you require.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did in the end. The main (.NET) app sets APPDOMAIN_MANAGER_TYPE and APPDOMAIN_MANAGER_ASM environment variables to cause a custom AppDomainManager to be used, which overrides InitializeNewDomain to set the AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile property to point to the shared .exe.config file. Easy when you know how!

Answer (score 12):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @configFile);

Comment: more on this here: http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/01/10/349825.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can force the application to read a particular config file using

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(PATH_TO_CONFIG);
```

Comment: Thanks. I need this to become the "default" app.config file so that e.g. WCF settings are read from it. I'll update the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting your configuration in a XML serialized object.